# What am I overriding in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

A lot of tutorials on UITableView asks us to override this function in `MyUITableViewController: UITableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
```

I understand this is an implementation of the numberOfRowsInSection method in `UITableView` but I don't understand the language mechanism.

`tableView` is an inherited property of `UITableViewController`, not a method. So how exactly does the override work?

Comment: This is just swift's goofy way of helping to conforming to Objective-C's verbose function names. I believe tableView is actually a function and it has several different sets of parameters that in turn defines several different functions. You're simply overriding the function with that particular set of parameters.

Comment: @TravisM. is correct. In ObjC a method name is the equivalent to the concatenation of the function name and all named parameters.

Comment: But `tableView` is not a method. Inside `UITableViewController`, you see `var tableView: UITableView!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewController` conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html

`tableView` is a protocol function defined in `UITableViewDataSource`

`UITableViewController` has a default implementation of protocol functions which `MyUITableViewController` can `override`.

Answer (score 3):

The objective-C syntax of that same method is

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section;
```

which gives a method signature of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`

When you are used to Objective-C you kind of mentally ignore the `tableView:` part and focus on the `numberOfRowsInSection`.

When the Objective-C method name is converted to swift, the first parameter becomes the method name so you get `tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`

The short answer to your question is that you are overriding the function with that signature, not the `tableView` property